# Accessing fields of an iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe, dom

I read that the following should work in order to access the contents of an iframe with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_name").contentDocument
```

or

```
document.getElementyById("iframe_name").contentWindow.document
```

However, neither of those methods work for me. The iframe I am trying to access is a Google form that I created. It is a registration form that I created for my website. I want to do some calculation on some of the fields that the user types in then display it after the iframe. Accessing those fields using javascript is the best way I could think of. Why can't I access it? Is there maybe a better way to achieve my goal? Thank you.

Comment: This looks correct. What is telling you that these methods are not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can't acces external page like google.com from your server.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is it. Thanks. Anyway, what I did in the end is simply copy the code inside the iframe (which is simply a Google form) and then I could both manipulate it however I want and I could also access it. In the end, all there is to it is the POST request that it does (to a certain URL that Google creates for the form). Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct. Here is a more complete sequence that should work cross-browser:

```
var ifr=document.getElementById("iframe_name");
var doc=ifr.contentWindow||ifr.contentDocument;
if (doc.document) doc=doc.document;
```

Update: as said in another answer, this won't work across domains (for example if you try to access google.com from mydomain.com).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you wishing to do but maybe this will help you..

I used this to reload the frame

```
document.getElementById('graphFrame').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

you can see that the location attribute is related to the iframe.

Next, I am changing a div inside an Iframe like this.

```
top.frames["graphFrame"].document.getElementById('right_example');
```

So the top.frames is array of the page frames. then i am searching for a dom element which his ID is "right_example" then you can do what ever you want with that.